# cannot open google now

Tags: launcher, google-now, samsung-touchwiz

I have Samsung Galaxy S2 Plus(GT-I9105) with rooted stock android 4.1.2.
So I thought of replacing touchwiz with Google Now Launcher. So, I installed Google Now from Play store. When I try to open it, It gives a message

"Touchwiz Home is currently your default launcher, go to settings, touch Clear Defaults and press the Home Button."

The problem is Touchwiz is not set to default (the button is disabled) as it is the only launcher I have.
Pressing Home button doesn't show Google Now Launcher.
I installed other launchers, and they work fine.Only Google Now has the problem. Is it a bug? Anything I should do?

Comment: I have same issue on lava x9 android 5.0. .... You got any solutions ? Have google search and now installed

Comment: Sadly, No solutions came up, I am using a different phone now, and it has Google now working fine...

Answer (score 3):

You need to install the google search apk before the google now launcher

Comment: Google Search is installed by default. Its also up to date.

Comment: I had a Galaxy Tab 3 with kitkat 4.4.2 and Touchwiz with the same problem until I installed the Google app, the google app version is 4.1.24.1672412.arm from 12 jan 2015.

Comment: i have the same version of google installed..